# Create a new table in MySQL workbench by importing a csv file

Tags: mysql, csv, import, mysql-workbench

It's my first time on MySQL workbench, and I want to import a csv file from one of my folders to MySQL.
To do so I right clicked on one of my tables, imported the file with the wizard by writing its path in my laptop, but I cant selesct any destination for the table to be created :[image: What goes wrong with MySQL workbench]
I don't know very much about the software to be honest, has anyone an idea on how I could finish to import my file ?

The software doesn't let me the opportunity to create a table...

Comment: Next to create new table in the dropdown select the database (Schema) you want to add the new table to, the the csv files name is used in the fields after the `.` Youcan change that if you like

Comment: The main point is that I can't do anything with the dropdown...

Comment: Have you created a database yet? You have to have a database in order to create a table inside it. Databases exists inside the DBMS(MySQL) and tables exists inside a Database. Then columns exists inside a table.

Comment: I created a file anq I'm connected on my local server but I don't know much... How to create a data base ?

Comment: It seems to have worked finally, I just created a new scheme in utf-8 (the default encoding failed)